# FileLoadException after NuGet Update

Tags: c#, .net, nuget, unity-container

After doing an update of all NuGet packages, one of my applications began crashing on start-up with a `FileLoadException`:

```
Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.Practices.ServiceLocation, Version=1.2.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35' or one of its dependencies.
```

This was after upgrading `ServiceLocation` to version 1.3.0.0, and I double-checked all assemblies to ensure that they were using that version. I then ran `Fuslogvw` to diagnose the assembly that was still referencing the old version:

```
LOG: DisplayName = Microsoft.Practices.ServiceLocation, Version=1.2.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35
(Fully-specified)
LOG: Appbase = file:///C:/Users/Charlie/AppData/Local/Programs/MyClient/
LOG: Initial PrivatePath = NULL
LOG: Dynamic Base = NULL
LOG: Cache Base = NULL
LOG: AppName = MyClient.exe
Calling assembly : Microsoft.Practices.Prism.UnityExtensions, Version=5.0.1.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35.
===
```

So, **`UnityExtensions`** (another NuGet package) is still referencing the old version. But that should be OK, because I've added a `bindingRedirect` to my app.config file:

```
<assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">
  <dependentAssembly>
    <assemblyIdentity name="Microsoft.Practices.ServiceLocation" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" culture="neutral" />
    <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-1.2.0.0" newVersion="1.3.0.0" />
  </dependentAssembly>
</assemblyBinding>
```

But this seems to make no difference. My application is targeting .NET Framework 4.5.1, and I've tried it with `AutoGenerateBindingRedirects` on and off. In other words, I've tried literally everything. What is going on here?

Comment: Did you use NuGet's built in tool for doing BindingRedirects? I my experience I've gotten them wrong doing it by hand: http://www.michael-whelan.net/nuget-add-bindingredirect/

Comment: Yeah, the redirect was generated automatically.

Comment: I ended up redoing all my package references, one by one, and intentionally moving them down to version 1.2 of ServiceLocation. :(

Comment: You cut your Fuslogvw.exe trace off at *exactly* the critical moment, when it was about to report what config it is using.  Post the entire trace.

Comment: probably a reason to set `UseSpecificVersion` to false in references. Anyways since most of the dlls being referenced are local references and not from GAC it is advisable to remove version and public key info from the reference name.

Comment: uninstall all Prism & unity extensions nuget package then install it again, it should work with the right version.

Comment: I had the same problem and just deleted the binding redirects and it worked for me.

Answer (score 1):

All you need to solve this issue is to update all PRISM and Unity related packages in all projects. Editing of binding redirects in not required.

See details on [codeplex](https://unity.codeplex.com/workitem/12767)

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried changing your binding redirect to be like this:

```
<assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">
    <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="Microsoft.Practices.ServiceLocation" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" culture="neutral" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-1.3.0.0" newVersion="1.3.0.0" />
    </dependentAssembly>
</assemblyBinding>
```

Note that I only change the oldVersion upper bound from **1.2.0.0** to **1.3.0.0** to catch any version up to 1.3 and redirect it.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure your references in config files are actually using the correct version. They could be out of sync with what NuGet installed.

Answer (score 1):

*This wasn't given in your example, but may help others ending up here like me.*

Make sure that you haven't got a wrong .NET version set.

e.g. `appliesTo="v2.0.50727"` will not work when using .NET 4+

```
<assemblyBinding appliesTo="v2.0.50727" xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">
    <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="Microsoft.Practices.ServiceLocation" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" culture="neutral" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-1.3.0.0" newVersion="1.3.0.0" />
    </dependentAssembly>
</assemblyBinding>
```